# How to Test Local Notifications in Apple Watch Simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, watchkit, uilocalnotification, apple-watch

I am developing an iOS app which will show Local Notifications and Local Interactive Notifications while it is in background. I want to test how it is displayed in the paired Apple Watch when the device is locked. Since I don't have an Apple Watch, how could I test this in the Simulator?

Answer (score 3):

If you get your iOS app notification working using simulator, then add some logic like triggering notification after 5 seconds of IBAction. Simple lock your iOS simulator using (Command ⌘ + L). Now the notification will be displayed on both the devices.

Comment: This is great! Small addition to the answer. Instead of triggering notification in the iOS app. You can create a notification payload, save it to a json file and drag & drop it to iPhone Simulator while it is locked. Here is and example of the payload https://gist.github.com/devValley/c465e1c7b1043ee4fa7c6aec59fa4371